# UiAutomator UiSelector childSelector or equivalent but with advanced conditionals?

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, android-uiautomator

I'm struggling to identify any support to negate expressions when using the [Android UiAutomator API](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/package-summary).

I currently have a RecyclerView with several ViewGroup nested to it, and they can be either collapsed or not.

The XML looks like this:

```
<RecyclerView resource-id="application_list">
  <ViewGroup resource-id="product_detail_view">
    <TextView resource-id="product_date" />
    <TextView resource-id="product_price" />
  </ViewGroup>
  <ViewGroup resource-id="product_detail_view">
    <TextView resource-id="product_date" />
    <TextView resource-id="product_price" />
    <TextView resource-id="product_information" />    
  </ViewGroup>
</RecyclerView>
```

Where, when it is collapsed, I don't see the TextView `product_information`. When I click it, it gets expanded and then I can see it.

With Appium, I am trying to use the method `scrollIntoView` to go to the next collapsed ViewGroup, i.e., the next ViewGroup without a TextView with resource-id `product_information` is the next one that is collapsed.

My first attempt was the following, but it obviously do not work, because the provided regex will match either `product_date` or `product_price` from the available children, and since they exist on both collapsed and expanded ViewGroups, the behavior of capturing the next collapsed one is not achieved.

```
const untrackedElement = `android=
    new UiScrollable(
        new UiSelector()
            .scrollable(true)
            .instance(0)
    )
    .scrollIntoView(
        new UiSelector()
            .resourceId("product_detail_view")
            .childSelector(
                new UiSelector()
                    .resourceIdMatches("^(?!product_information).*$")
            )
    )
`.replace(/[\n\t]+/g, '');

await $(untrackedElement);
```

Is there a way to negate childSelector? For example,

```
            .childSelector(
                new UiSelector()
                    .resourceId("product_information")
            )
            .childCount(0) // None found

////////////////////////////////////
            .not( condition ) // Similar?
```

Or, pehaps, a way to add multiple childSelector conditions? So that it takes into consideration multiple aspects of multiple children before identifying the target ViewGroup? For example:

```
            .childSelector(
                new UiSelector()
                    .resourceId("product_date")
                    .textContains("01/01/0001")
                , // Lookup into two children, date and price respectively
                new UiSelector()
                    .resourceId("product_price")
                    .textContains("1,111.11")
            )
```